# Getting two tables in LaTeX to have the same (right-aligned) column width

Tags: alignment, latex, tabular

I have two very short and consecutive sections (for a CV), each containing a small table:

```
\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
Current & Your job at Your Company, Town \\
Jan 2009 & What your company does \\
& A description of what you do\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\ 
\end{tabular}

\section{Education}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
Slightly wider first column & University, Town \\
Jan 2009 & Thesis subject \\
& A description of what you did\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\ 
\end{tabular}
```

So each table has two columns: The first containing the period, aligned to the right. The second: some more info with a certain width, top (and left) aligned.

The **problem** is that the width of the left column in the two tables is different, and doesn't look nice since the sections (therefore tables) are consecutive and in one page. I cannot give `r` a width like `p`:

```
\begin{tabular}{r{11cm}|p{11cm}}
```

Does not work. How can I get the widths of the first columns of the two tables the same length while also having them right aligned?

**EDIT** Thanks for the answers, they all work for me so I upvoted all of them, and accepted the one that appealed to me the most (and most upvoted), since you don't have to specify the `\hfill` in each row. However if you don't want to use the *array* package for any reason then the other solutions are also great.

Comment: Not an answer to you questions as such, but I use the currvita package to maintain my CV (well, with suitable hacks...): http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/currvita/ . That way *you* don't have to deal with these details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, well check it out for the next version :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use the `array` package, you can put the `\hfill` in the header as follows, so you don't have to remember to put it (or a `\parbox`) in each row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{>{\hfill}p{5cm}|p{11cm}}
  Current & Your job at Your Company, Town \\
  Jan 2009 & What your company does \\
  & A description of what you do\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} 
\end{tabular}

\section{Education}

\begin{tabular}{>{\hfill}p{5cm}|p{11cm}}
  Slightly wider first column & University, Town \\
  Jan 2009 & Thesis subject \\
  & A description of what you did\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

to give:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5e29f675e3.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5e29f675e3.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a variant of @RTBarnard's answer using the `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,draft,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft}X|p{8cm}}
Current & Your job at Your Company, Town \\
Jan 2009 & What your company does \\
& A description of what you do\\
\end{tabularx}

\section{Education}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft}X|p{8cm}}
Somewhat wider than first column, 
overflowing into additional lines & University, Town \\
Jan 2009 & Thesis subject \\
& A description of what you did\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Notes:

1. Why `tabularx`? Because it's often
   easier to know the width you have
   available for the whole table, and
   to let TeX calculate the unknown
   column widths.
2. The first parameter is the overall table width.  Here, I've specified `\textwidth` to fill the width of typeblock, but you can change that to whatever measure you need.
3. I've used `\raggedright` rather than `\hfill`: if the item flows onto a second line, `\hfill` will only right-align the first line of the paragraph.
4. Was the `\multicol` significant? I've removed it to keep the answer as simple as possible.

Run with XeTeX under TeXLive.

Comment: For completion, i would note that if you wanna put that spec on the last column, you need to reset the meaning of "\\" using `\arraybackslash`.

Comment: Hey, didn't know that, could you elaborate?

Comment: `\raggedleft` changes the meaning of `\\ ` to do various magic stuffs. See `{\ttfamily\meaning\raggedleft}`. `\arraybackslash` will change its meaning back to that of the tabular environment. These changes affect only the current group, so you will see compile errors only in the last column.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution of many possibilities:

```
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
\parbox{11cm}{\hfill Current} & Your job at Your Company, Town \\
Jan 2009 & What your company does \\
& A description of what you do\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\ 
\end{tabular}
```

Basically, create a `\parbox` with the desired width and put an `\hfill` at the left.

Answer (score 1):

You can give both p{width} options, and start each cell in the left with an `\hfill`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array` package to specify a fill command for each row in your first column:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\hfill}p{11cm}|p{11cm}|}
```

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\hfill}p{5cm}|p{11cm}|}
This is a test & test
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{>{\hfill}p{5cm}|p{11cm}|}
Test & this is a test
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```